# VB.NET Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String path) never (or always) loads DLL file even if actually (or not) present at path

Tags: vb.net

VB.NET 4.5 here.
In order to dynamically load a class type from an external library, please take a look at my snippet of code from a thread context:

```
While (True)
    Dim MyClassName = "MyNamespace.MyClass,MyNamespace"
    Dim MyLibPath = "C:\Libs\MyLib.dll"

    Sleep(3000)

    Try
        Dim MyClass As Type = _
            Type.GetType(MyClassName, _
                         Function(AssemResolv) Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(MyLibPath), _
                         Nothing, _
                         False, _
                         True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End While
```

that is, every 3 secs load my class from my lib at that path.
Please refrain from making me notice that is useless to load the type at every loop, this snippet is just an example.

At this point my problem is that everything works fine as long as the libraries are already present at the path when the program launches, but if I try to erase the dll from C:\Libs while program is running, the dll continues being found and the type being loaded.

Same happens if the dll is not present at launch: if I copy it at the given path, the program continues not finding it. But, again if I stop and relaunch the dll is found.

Why does this happen?
How can I make the program to notice when a dll is copied/erased to/from the path?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:
I solved this way:

```
While (True)
    Dim MyClassName = "MyNamespace.MyClass,MyNamespace"
    Dim MyLibName = "MyLib"
    Dim MyLibPath = "C:\Libs\MyLib.dll"

    Sleep(3000)

    Try
        Dim MyClass As Type = _
            Type.GetType(TypeStr, _
            Function(AssemResolv) If(AssemResolv.Name = MyLibName, _
                                     Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(MyLibPath), _
                                     Nothing), _
            Function(assem, name, ignore) If(assem Is Nothing, _
                                             Type.GetType(name, False, ignore), _
                                             assem.GetType(name, False, ignore)), _
            False, _
            True)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End While
```

In other words I used the Assembly.LoadFile (that is expecting a real FS path) in place of the Assembly.LoadFrom (which is expecting a URI) and implemented better assembly and type resolvers.
Now libraries are loaded when copied into the directory and not loaded when for example you change name to the dll file, and all of this while the program is running.

Comment: The CLR will consistently return the exact same result from an assembly load if one was performed before.  So if it was loaded once then it will always succeed if you do it again.  If the first load failed then it will always fail if you do it again, even if you copy the assembly while the program is running.  This is an important DLL Hell counter-measure.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: Well actually I solved. Now they are loading when I copy a dll to the path, probably you were reffering to some other feature/scenario? Look at my edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this way:

```
While (True)
    Dim MyClassName = "MyNamespace.MyClass,MyNamespace"
    Dim MyLibName = "MyLib"
    Dim MyLibPath = "C:\Libs\MyLib.dll"

    Sleep(3000)

    Try
        Dim MyClass As Type = _
            Type.GetType(TypeStr, _
            Function(AssemResolv) If(AssemResolv.Name = MyLibName, _
                                     Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(MyLibPath), _
                                     Nothing), _
            Function(assem, name, ignore) If(assem Is Nothing, _
                                             Type.GetType(name, False, ignore), _
                                             assem.GetType(name, False, ignore)), _
            False, _
            True)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End While
```

In other words I used the Assembly.LoadFile (that is expecting a real FS path) in place of the Assembly.LoadFrom (which is expecting a URI) and implemented better assembly and type resolvers.
Now libraries are found and loaded when copied into the directory and not found and loaded when for example you change name to the dll file, and all of this while the program is running.